# Brightcove ad mid-rolls in HTML5 video using a VAST ad server?

Tags: html, brightcove, vast

I'm trying to get mid-rolls working in the Brightcove HTML5 player.  The ads are being supplied by a VAST2-compliant ad server.

From reading all the Brightcove documents and developer resources, I'm reaching the conclusion that this is simply not possible.  Is my conclusion correct?

My main findings:

- 1 If the player is configured with the "VAST Server Ad Source", then according to this document http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/using-vast-server-ad-source-publishers :

> "the VAST Server ad source for the HTML player does **not** support
>   onload and mid-roll ads."

So I switched gears and followed the documents to instead write a custom HTML5 ad plugin. I'm at the point where I receive the Mid-roll Ad CUE events and make calls to the ad server. That leads to:

- 2 With the ad server VAST response in-hand, according to this document http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/creating-ad-plug-html-players :

> "Since the first iteration of our ad plugin system is not exposing any
>   way to pass ad XML to the Brightcove player to be displayed, **an ad
>   plugin must modify the video element** during ad playback to play a
>   video ad"

My conclusion is that in case 2 above, I have to essentially manipulate a barebones < video > element with no VAST help whatsoever from brightcove - this would mean re-implementing all of VAST client-side player features from scratch (redirection, unwrapping, playing, tracking, click-handling, companions, etc..) - or - incorporating and using a third-party VAST library or player inside the plugin that does all of this stuff while still complying with the Brightcove ad module flow.

I'm hoping I've missed some documentation or there's some sane middle-ground to get this working.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked 2 years trying to make VAST and HTML5 work from a common browser without any success, if you want it for non-native HTML5 packaged mobile app, there is a solution using Cordova Framework.